# Как устроен static class

Tags: java

В интернете нашёл пример неправильного использования ThreadLocal переменной и внутренних классов.

```
 class X {
  ThreadLocal<Anchor> local = new ThreadLocal<Anchor>();
  class Anchor {
    byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
  }
  public Anchor getOrCreate() {
    Anchor res = local.get();
    if (res == null) {
      res = new Anchor();
      local.set(res);
    }
    return res;
  }
  public static void doLeakOneMoreInstance() {
    new X().getOrCreate();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    while (true) {
      doLeakOneMoreInstance();
      System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB of heap left");
    }
  }
}
```

Если объявить статиком class Anchor почему не происходит утечка памяти? Я всегда считал что статик класс объявляется для удобства создания класса например чтобы не делать так a.new B(), а делать вот так new A.B()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утечка памяти у тебя происходи не из-за `Anchor`
А из-за того что ты в цикле while каждый раз создаешь новый объект `X` в котором создаётся новый объект `Anchor`

Вот если использовать объект `X` только один, никакой утечки нет

```
class X {
    ThreadLocal<Anchor> local = new ThreadLocal<Anchor>();
    class Anchor {
        byte[] data = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    }
    public Anchor getOrCreate() {
        Anchor res = local.get();
        if (res == null) {
            res = new Anchor();
            local.set(res);
        }
        return res;
    }
    public static void doLeakOneMoreInstance(X xObject) {
        xObject.getOrCreate();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        X xObject = new X(); // используем один единственный X
        while (true) {
            doLeakOneMoreInstance(xObject);
            System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024 / 1024 + " MB of heap left");
        }
    }
}
```

А когда ты делаешь статик класс `Anchor`, то просто не создаётся новый экземпляр. А так у тебя в ThreadLocal просто плодится бесконечно много объектов Anchor

Comment: Кстати если сделать переменную local статичной, то так-же не будет плодится объекты Anchor